# C unix domain sockets, recvfrom() doesn't set struct sockaddr* src_addr

Tags: c, sockets, unix, udp, unix-socket

I'm writing an application that listens for UDP packets over a unix domain socket. Consider the following code block.

```
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_un servaddr;

sockfd = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

if(sockfd < 0)
{
    perror("socket() failed");
}

unlink(port);

bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
strcpy(servaddr.sun_path, port);    

if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
{
    perror("bind() failed");
    close(sockfd);
}

int n;
struct sockaddr_un cliaddr;
socklen_t len = sizeof(cliaddr);
discovery_msgs client_message;


bzero(&client_message, sizeof(client_message));
// Wait for a message to be received
n = recvfrom(sock_fd, &client_message, sizeof(client_message), 0, 
    (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &len);

// At this point n = 560, client_message is filled with the expected data 
//len = 0 and cliaddr has no information about the client that sent the data
```

Now the type of `client_message` isn't really important, I'm receiving a UDP packet and `client_message` contains all of the data I expect. The problem begins when I look at `cliaddr` and `len` after calling `recvfrom`. `cliaddr` is not modified by `recvfrom` like it normally is with normal network TCP/UDP and `len` is set to 0 after the call(which means recvfrom wrote no data to `&cliaddr`). I need the information in `cliaddr` to be populated with the unix domain path so I can send a response.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try some error checking. What are the values returned by `socket(),` `bind(),` and `recvfrom()?`

Comment: As mentioned in the question, all error checking was done(including socket(), bind(), and recvfrom()) and all calls successfully returned. n = 560 and client_message is populated with expected data from the client's packet.

Comment: You check cliaddr, len immediately after the recvfrom() returns?  You have a breakpoint on the next line and a no optimization build?   Just wondering if your debugger is telling porkies..

Comment: Correct, I was seeing errors when trying to reuse `cliaddr` to send a response which first tipped me off. Optimization is off, breakpoint is immediately after the call to `recvfrom()`.

Comment: OK, I've got nuthin.. :((

Comment: Note that POSIX [`recvfrom()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recvfrom.html) says: _Not all protocols provide the source address for messages._  Maybe it is reasonable to deduce that Unix domain sockets do not provide a source address; it seems reasonable to me, though I've not found the standard words that formalize that.

Comment: Is it possible that you need to bind your socket to a port(path) with unix domain if you want your address to be attached with the sent message?

I dont see that happening in the Stevens Unix Programming book examples.

Comment: Hmm, maybe.  Every time I've ever used UDP I've been able to get the source address.  This problem annoys me.  It's a good question, the OP has done some debugging AND I CAN'T SEE ANYTHING WRONG!!

Comment: scratch that, it looks like the client is binding in the stevens book and it states the exact reason is to send a reply address. Doh

Comment: @user2278457 I've been grasping at straws with this and I've now run out of straw.

Comment: I guess you could check the incoming datagram with wireshark and see if it's well-formed with a source address.

Comment: Okay, it seemingly started working, the solution is indeed binding the socket on the client side otherwise the transient port created for sending the UDP packet immediately disappears after sendto(). See Stevens Network Programming page 419 or see this for an example: http://www.libpix.org/unp/unixdgcli01_8c_source.html

Answer (score 10):

The solution is binding the socket on the client side when using Unix domain sockets. Otherwise the transient pathname created for sending the UDP packet immediately disappears after `sendto()`, which explains why the client's address information is not available on the server side.

See Stevens Network Programming page 419 or see this for an example client implementation that solves this issue: libpix.org/unp/unixdgcli01_8c_source.html

```
#include    "unp.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_un  cliaddr, servaddr;

    sockfd = Socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    bzero(&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));       /* bind an address for us */
    cliaddr.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
    strcpy(cliaddr.sun_path, tmpnam(NULL));

    Bind(sockfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); /* fill in server's address */
    servaddr.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
    strcpy(servaddr.sun_path, UNIXDG_PATH);

    dg_cli(stdin, sockfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    exit(0);
}
```

Note: `unp.h` defines `Bind()` which is simply `bind()` with some error checking(commonly used throughout Stevens Network Programming). In the same manner, `(SA *)` is the equivalent to `(struct sockaddr *)`.

Comment: I use same way in my program. But what server should do to close peer fd if using sock_dgram unix socket. Is it not necessary like udp?